# Removing unwanted JSON data using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, json, cloudant, nosql

I'm new to JSON and Javascript and had to make a table in Cloudant NoSQL.
So, I collected Weather data from a Weather Company in JSON format and sent it to Cloudant, but there was some data in JSON which wasn't relevant to the table I wanted to create. 
Is there a way to remove the metadata and the column name "observation" from the JSON data I received using javascript?

JSON data I have:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "language": "en-US",
    "transaction_id": "1503766402801:1454518918",
    "version": "1",
    "latitude": 12.83,
    "longitude": 77.68,
    "expire_time_gmt": 1503771300,
    "status_code": 200
  },
  "observation": {
    "key": "43295",
    "class": "observation",
    "expire_time_gmt": 1503771300,
    "obs_id": "43295",
    "obs_name": "Bangalore",
    "valid_time_gmt": 1503759600,
    "day_ind": "N",
    "temp": 75,
    "wx_icon": 29
  }
}
```

JSON data I want

```
{
    "_id": "2e5e0da1f82157dd6f5d381a4c9ff84e",
    "_rev": "1-b7a92ae5f96b051f0add3b26a14543c2",
    "key": "43295",
    "class": "observation",
    "expire_time_gmt": 1503771300,
    "obs_id": "43295",
    "obs_name": "Bangalore",
    "valid_time_gmt": 1503759600,
    "day_ind": "N",
    "temp": 75,
    "wx_icon": 29
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT
I'm able to remove metadata using "delete data.metadata;", where data contains the JSON, but I still can't remove the "observation" word and the curly braces in the end.

Comment: try using delete operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: I used delete operator to remove metadata, but I still can't remove other words.

Comment: okay, so you want the data of observation object, in the root of the object?

Comment: yes @RaghavGarg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON is parsed, you can just assign all keys from all nested objects to a new object.

```js
var myData = {
  "metadata": {
    "language": "en-US",
    "transaction_id": "1503766402801:1454518918",
    "version": "1",
    "latitude": 12.83,
    "longitude": 77.68,
    "expire_time_gmt": 1503771300,
    "status_code": 200
  },
  "observation": {
    "key": "43295",
    "class": "observation",
    "expire_time_gmt": 1503771300,
    "obs_id": "43295",
    "obs_name": "Bangalore",
    "valid_time_gmt": 1503759600,
    "day_ind": "N",
    "temp": 75,
    "wx_icon": 29
  }
}

myData = Object.keys(myData)
    .reduce((res, key) => Object.assign(res, myData[key]), {});

console.log(myData);
```

There are some extra keys in your result. Not sure where those are coming from.

If there are some extra properties to delete, you can use `delete` to get rid of those.

```
["latitude", "longitude"].forEach(k => delete myData[k]);
```

---

Or perhaps I misunderstood. I though you wanted a consolidation. If you only wanted the observation object, then just assign it to the original variable.

```
myData = myData.observation;
```

And add whatever other properties you'd like.

Comment: Thank you so much. Had been breaking my head over this the whole day. worked miracles.

Comment: @JavaforAndroid: Oh wait, you wanted to only have the `observation` properties? Then it's just `myData = myData.observation`, and add whatever extra keys you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new json object before sending. Using lodash should be an easy solution in extending

```
// Assume result has your json data
var wantedJson = _.extend({}, result.observation, result.metadata);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bothered about the order of the elements, this is the simplest way:

```js
var result = {
  "metadata": {
    "language": "en-US",
    "transaction_id": "1503766402801:1454518918",
    "version": "1",
    "latitude": 12.83,
    "longitude": 77.68,
    "expire_time_gmt": 1503771300,
    "status_code": 200
  },
  "observation": {
    "key": "43295",
    "class": "observation",
    "expire_time_gmt": 1503771300,
    "obs_id": "43295",
    "obs_name": "Bangalore",
    "valid_time_gmt": 1503759600,
    "day_ind": "N",
    "temp": 75,
    "wx_icon": 29
  }
}
var myjson = result.observation;
myjson._id = "2e5e0da1f82157dd6f5d381a4c9ff84e",
myjson._rev = "1-b7a92ae5f96b051f0add3b26a14543c2";
console.log(myjson);
```